# Activerecord linking 2 tables

Tags: activerecord

I have been able to make 2 ActiveRecord tables, **Profile** and **Bot**. I have been unable to figure out how to link them properly.

There are thousands of **Profiles** with columns **username, gender**. A handful of **Bots** with columns **botname, level**

When a bot visits a profile two pieces of info need to be recorded. **visited** and **response** should be updated for that specific bot. **visited** is a boolean that will indicate that one particular bot has visited that one particular profile. the **response** is a string, again like the **visited** this is a response for one particular bot that was sent by one particular profile. I am thinking I need a 3rd table that joins these two tables.

I need to keep a record of every profile that every bot visits and the response that happens when it visits.

How can I create this relationship and how can I set/update the columns?

Thanks

Comment: What data is stored in the values "visited" and "response"?  And do you need to keep track of every profile that a bot visits?  Or just the last profile a bot visited?

Comment: Question updated to answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not completely certain of your requirements, so I will restate them:

1. Table Profile:  id, username, gender  (note that I changed the table names to singular)
2. Table Bot: id, botname, level
3. The "bots" somehow "visit" profiles.  You need to track when a bot has visited a profile.
4. When a bot visits a profile, a "response" string is generated and that response string needs to be preserved.  I'm assuming it needs to be preserved with the record of the visit.

I think your instincts about a join table are good.  I don't think a boolean "visited" column works, however, because if you have a record of a visit, that's an indication that the profile was visited.  If the record doesn't exist, then it wasn't visited.

Given this, I think your tables look like this:

```
profile 
---------
profile_id integer autoincrement
username varchar(255)
gender ...

bot
---------
bot_id integer autoincrement
name varchar(255)
level ...

visit
---------
visit_id integer autoincrement
bot_id integer
profile_id integer
visit_time datetime
response varchar(255)
```

To maintain the integrity of your data, you'll want to set up foreign key constraints between this visit table and your profile and bot tables.

```
alter table visit
    add constraint visit_profile_profile_id_fk 
    foreign key (profile_id) 
    references profile (profile_id);

alter table visit
    add constraint visit_bot_bot_id_fk 
    foreign key (bot_id) 
    references profile (bot_id);
```

You'll need to decide if it's "legal" for a given bot to visit a particular profile more than once.  If it's not, you should put a unique constraint on the combination of profile_id and bot_id in the visit table, and catch the duplicate key errors when your DBMS throws them at you (or otherwise handle dupes.)

I hope that helps.